# How authenticate users and store data in MongoDB with Express in production?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, authentication, session

I'm currently building a simple Express API with a user authentication and some data to be stored. Right now in production I'm using passport-local authentication and a cookie session to authenticate users, but I heard that in production that is not really good.

Why are other authentication methods better and which authentication would be save, stable and scalable? Also what speaks against cookie-session? Is express-session with connect-mongo better and why?

Comment: i use for APIs motsly Json Web Tokens (JWT). With them you dont have any issues if your create microservices over more (sub-)domains. But it truly depends on your application structure and what you do with that app. What are the reason for " I heard that in production that is not really good" ?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [this article](https://www.taniarascia.com/full-stack-cookies-localstorage-react-express/) from Tania Rascia. It covers using Express with JSONWebTokens (JWT) and OAuth with Cookies. It's a secure method and it all runs on the same server (backend and front end served with express).